# I cannot figure out how to clear the local store when using dcc.Store

Tags: plotly-dash

I am messing about with the dcc.Store  (https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/store)

There is a clear_data attribute but I cannot figure out how to get it to work.  I want to add an html button to clear the local store.

All I am doing is incrementing a variable, storing it and reading it back ... the example given by Dash does not give any indication how to clear the values

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Store(id='buttonstore3', storage_type='local'),

    html.Div([
        html.Button('Local', id='my-button3')
    ]),

    html.Div([
        html.Button('Clear Local', id='my-button4')
    ]),


    html.Div([
        html.Table([
            html.Thead([
                html.Tr([
                    html.Th('Local clicks')
                ])
            ]),
            html.Tbody([
                html.Tr([
                    html.Td(0, id='local-clicks'),
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ])


])


####### Add to Local Store
@app.callback(Output('buttonstore3', 'data'),
                [Input('my-button3', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('buttonstore3', 'data')])
def on_click(n_clicks, data):
    if n_clicks  is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    data = data or 0
    data = data + 1
    return data


@app.callback(Output('local-clicks', 'children'),
                [Input('buttonstore3', 'modified_timestamp')],
                [State('buttonstore3', 'data')])
def on_data(ts, data):
    if ts is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    data = data or 0
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says in the docs [here](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/store):

> clear_data - Set to True to remove the data contained in data_key.

So you could add the following callback to your app:

```py
@app.callback(Output('buttonstore3', 'clear_data'),
            [Input('my-button4', 'n_clicks')])
def clear_click(n_click_clear):
    if n_click_clear is not None and n_click_clear > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

You could also update your `on_click` callback to take in inputs from both buttons, and output to the `data` prop based on which button was clicked, like this:

```py
####### Add to Local Store
@app.callback(Output('buttonstore3', 'data'),
                [Input('my-button3', 'n_clicks'),
                Input('my-button4', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('buttonstore3', 'data')])
def on_click(n_clicks_add, n_clicks_clear, data):
    if n_clicks_add is None:
        n_clicks_add = 0
    if n_clicks_clear is None:
        n_clicks_clear = 0
    if data is None:
        data = 0

    trigger = dash.callback_context.triggered[0]

    if trigger['prop_id'] == 'my-button3.n_clicks':
        data += 1
    elif trigger['prop_id'] == 'my-button4.n_clicks':
        data = 0
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unrecognized trigger: {}'.format(trigger['prop_id']))

    return data
```

Comment: Thank you so much @coralvanda both of these work a treat.  I had been looking into grabbing the input of both buttons - the info on that is stuck in the FAQ section of the Dash docs.  Nice one Eric.

Comment: Great answer, sometimes I miss things when I read documentation.